# IoT Hub Baltimore to DigiCert Migration?

Tags: azure, ssl, ssl-certificate, azure-iot-hub

As per the below article, we have to update the certificate from Baltimore to Digicert

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/internet-of-things-blog/azure-iot-tls-critical-changes-are-almost-here-and-why-you/ba-p/2393169

We have many devices connected through factories and they have firewalls in place. Do we need to open any specific port to support this newly updated DigiCert Global G2 Root certificate?

Based on the article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/fundamentals/tls-certificate-changes it says we need to ALLOW below urls. Is my understanding correct?

```
http://crl3.digicert.com
http://crl4.digicert.com
http://ocsp.digicert.com
http://crl.microsoft.com
http://oneocsp.microsoft.com
http://ocsp.msocsp.com
```

My second question: Do we still need the "Microsoft RSA Root Certificate Authority 2017" certificate?

My third question: What does it means "Make sure SHA384 for Server certificate processing is enabled on the device"

Microsoft document says, 1. If your devices use a connection stack other than the ones provided in an Azure IoT SDK, then action is required:

•   To continue without disruption due to this change, Microsoft recommends that client applications or devices trust the DigiCert Global G2 root:
DigiCert Global Root G2

•   To prevent future disruption, client applications or devices should also add the following root to the trusted store:
Microsoft RSA Root Certificate Authority 2017

So what does mean "If your devices use a connection stack other than the ones provided in an Azure IoT SDK, "????

Comment: Yes, based on the information provided in the article you mentioned, you need to allow specific URLs to support the newly updated DigiCert Global G2 Root certificate. Your understanding is correct, and you should allow the following URLs:

http://crl3.digicert.com
http://crl4.digicert.com
http://ocsp.digicert.com
http://crl.microsoft.com
http://oneocsp.microsoft.com
http://ocsp.msocsp.com

Comment: what does it means "Make sure SHA384 for Server certificate processing is enabled on the device." ?

Comment: ASFK we can upload the certificate to the Azure IoT hub in                                    [link1](https://i.imgur.com/7cHQWk6.png) and [link2](https://i.imgur.com/0WQpqWy.png)

Comment: That is on the server side. What about client devices? Do we need icrosoft RSA Root Certificate Authority 2017 on client machine along with Digicert Global G2?

Comment: hope this sdk helps ```var cert = new X509Certificate2("C:\\Tools\\cert\\MyCert.cer");
var auth = new DeviceAuthenticationWithX509Certificate("mydevice", cert);

var DClnt = DeviceClient.Create("HostName", auth);

var msg = new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Test message"));
await DClnt.SendEventAsync(msg);```